# Windows Form App data isn't inserting while connected to DB

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Finally got the app to connect to the SQL DB on the server.  But now the test data won't insert.

I'm getting no errors

```
private void BtnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnUpload.Enabled = false;
        Application.DoEvents();

        UploadFile(txtFTPAddress.Text, txtFilePath.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        btnUpload.Enabled = true;

        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        try
        {
            Conn.Open();
            string insertURL = "insert into modelGEOmodelData (ID, Name, Location, modelGeoURL) values (@ID, @Name, @Location, @modelGeoURL)";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertURL, Conn);
                string id = "1234";
                string name = "pump";
                string local = "redford";
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", id));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", name));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Location", local));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@modelGeoURL", FileURLtxt.Text));
                Conn.Close();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

Comment: You need to call `ExecuteNonQuery` method on `command` object to execute the statement.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to catch? There is no `Exception` to catch, and the catch block is empty. In this way, you will never got notified if exception is raised.

Comment: I have an Exception in the code.  Just not in here.

Comment: That was it @Hermanto  Thank you very much.